# How to get stream from camera to web page?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

I have started developing module which shows the live video stream from the camera on web page.

But, I don't know how to show the video stream live in web page.

Is there any JavaScript function helps to show live view?
Does object tag in HTML allow us to embed live video ?

Could someone guide me on how I can do this?

Comment: Just to be sure. You are trying to show a webcam stream from a remote server on a client's browser? Or a local webcam feed?

Comment: these camera should not play over internet. it can access only within industry.

Answer (score 7):

If you are mentioning about the Live Streaming. For this you either need Streaming Video Server or HTTP Streaming.

1. **Streaming Video Server**

   IT is the server from which you will stream your video. They have to be extremely fast, able to handle many connections at a time, depending on user's connection speed etc. To have this, you can

   - Buy your own, or
   - Sign up for a hosted streaming plan with an ISP (Internet Service Provider)
2. Or, you need **HTTP Streaming**

   To make it as simple as it can be

   - Create a video file in a common streaming media format
   - Upload the file to your web server
   - Make a simple hyperlink to the video file, or use special HTML tags to embed the video in a web page.

---

**Some helpful posts and plugins**

- [Video streaming over websockets using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript)
- [jQuery Video Player](http://jqueryvideo-player.com/jquery-webcam-video-streaming.html): Enables webcam video streaming
- [Video and Audio Streaming with Flash and Open Source Tools](http://freecode.com/articles/video-and-audio-streaming-with-flash-and-open-source-tools)
  <sub>And yes `<object>` tag, can be used to embed a video player which stream the data.</sub>
- **[Streaming over HTTP with JavaScript: AJAX video player](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16092/Streaming-over-HTTP-with-JavaScript-AJAX-video-pla) *<sup>Recommended, step by step guide</sup>***

Comment: It is difficult to download and upload to webserver and start playing the video. if we do that process means downloading process should happen in one thread and playing video should play on another thread, right ? we have number of camera plays with same ip and port with different channels. How to handle this process?

Comment: @Mohan, It really does not matter. Different camera means different video and different streams. They each will have individual link.

Comment: @Starx I am capturing videos using camera how do i post it to server i mean live?pleas help.

Comment: @ASahra What kind of camera do you have?

Comment: @Starx  it's a USB camera connected from client side but it might vary depending on users (clients)

Comment: @ASahra, If it's a USB Camera, my answer should be enough.

Comment: Can we record  video in `CCTV` and show it live in web page using `Javascript` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
        codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
        width="640" height="441" id="vlc" events="True">

    <param name="Src" value="rtsp://your camera ip address" />
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
    <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
    <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />

    <embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" quality="high" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="441"
           target="rtsp://your camera ip address" >               
    </embed>
```