# How to make a live web (audio+video) stream?

Tags: html, http, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am looking forward to make multiple live-streaming sessions at a website, like multiple "twitcams".

Is Flash Media Server the right thing for me, or what should i look for ? With FMS ill need the viewer and broadcaster. It is included ?

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to try websockets especially if you want to do multi-user-apps. there are thousands of tutorials.

probably the best solution:

[node.js](http://htttp://www.nodejs.org)

and here is a similar topic:

[stack-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript)

Comment: <device> in html5 spec is not avaliable in any browser yet, i'm looking for a production solition