# peer 2 peer libraries to broadcast real time video using websocket?

Tags: websocket, p2p, real-time-data

First of all, is it a nice and successfull idea to use peer 2 peer to broadcast realtime video ? I know that it will make the application scallable and will allow more users to get the real time video without affecting the server much, but are there drawbacks performance-wise and video quality-wise  ?

Now the specefic question, my intention is to share realtime video, and then use peer2peer in the webclient level using websockets, are there any libraries that are used for this purpose?

I know that streaming should be better using UDP but the follwing post says that even using websockets (TCP) at 30fps is fast ennough ([Video streaming over websockets using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript))

Answer (score 1):

[XSockets.NET](http://xsockets.net) provides a WebRTC API.
This will provide you a JavaScript API for P2P communication. You can actually have a video chat with 2 or more participants really easy.

If you are a .NET dev you can install the sample from nuget. That sample contains a example of a multivideo chat.

The video will be of high quality, but you can set parameters to get lower resolution if you have low bandwith.

WebRTC works in Chrome and Firefox today (as well as chrome 29 on android). You can try this site with Chrome (not updated for Firefox or mobile) http://browsermeeting.com/

[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XSockets.Sample.WebRTC)

Comment: I am not planning to use .NET, but since it is javascript I assume it is the same thing in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com) (disclaimer: I work @ FM), it'll help you do this.

I've actually built something along these lines for a client of ours, where each successive client becomes a potential "distribution" node. So X clients connect to the main server, and from there, other clients can connect to those clients (provided they have appropriate bandwidth/CPU/etc) for a re-broadcast version. It's sort of a supernode/mesh concept, and it works reasonably well.

Comment: this is excactely what I need! after making sure the clients have appropriate ressources: bandwidth/cpu etc etc thanks I will take a look when I get home, is this an open source solution ? or is it a paying one ?

Comment: It's a commercial product, but the community edition is free.

Comment: I will take a look, but since I am working on a academic project, I will probably implement my logic my self using peerConnection features, thanks.

By the way I am not really sending videos, but print screens (complete and partial) and cursor positions..