# How To Connect IP-Cam on Web Apps?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to build an web apps with connect ip cam function and image processing. but unfortunatelly i didn't know how to connect an ip-cam. if someone could provide a tutorial or something, that would be a real help.
Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript#4263239

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan thanks for your help