# Best practices for loading videos on a web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, video

Would like to understand how AirBnb is able to load a 20MB background video file so fast on their homepage. After inspecting their homepage on [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151105_5S_W9V/), I noticed that the video did not show up in any of the downloaded resources, which made it score so high. When I've tried this tactic, via loading the video asynchronously via AJAX, the video still shows up on WebPageTest as a downloaded resource, but just after the DOM loads. So I'm really not sure how AirBnb is able to make this work. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't see a background video on the site.

Comment: @KevinJantzer if you go to airbnb.com and wait a few seconds, the background image transforms into a video. If you inspect the DOM you will see this code inside of the hero: `<video preload="auto" loop="loop" id="pretzel-video" class="video-playing">` which then has two sources for the video, depending on your browser support. The videos are linked to `muscache.com`, which I imagine is AirBnb's CDN.

Comment: Looks like they stream it.

Comment: @j08691 could you explain that in more detail? As in with WebSockets? Like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AirBnb isn't doing anything special here.  They're just starting playback of media using progressive download, which just means playback starts while the video is still downloading.

On their CDN, they have uploaded some fairly large MP4 files with two important characteristics:

1. The indexing information (MOOV atom) has been moved to the beginning of the MP4 file
2. The video is encoded in a format and codec that your browser supports

Because of these characteristics, all the site has to do is tell your browser to begin playing the source URL, and it will do the right thing: it makes a web request to the CDN and begins downloading the file.  As soon as enough data has been transferred to start playback, it does so.

Finally, I can't say for sure why WebPageTest doesn't show you the video MP4s that are driving the video, but they are certainly there, and the URLs look like https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/Xxxxx-X1-1.mp4. I suspect they're looking at your User Agent to decide which file to send you, and are not sending any video at all to bots like Google and WebPageTest.

You're not getting the real story through WebPageTest.  Instead of relying on a third party to evaluate the page in their environment, you should watch the traffic you are actually being sent using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or the Network tab on Chrome Developer Tools.