# Webbased live video streaming from smartphone camera

Tags: android, html, azure, web, http-live-streaming

I am looking for a way to livestream videos from a smartphone camera inside a browser like Chrome or Edge. It should be able to transfer in protocols like RTMP, Fragmented MP4, or RTP/MPEG-2 Transport stream.

(Basically, I like to receive the livestream data on the Azure Media Service Portal)

I found similar [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server) but they require downloading an app.

The web solution needs to be open-source or based on Microsoft products/services.

Does anyone know a suitable approach?

I am not expecting code here, but rather naming open-source libraries or microsoft products that can be used to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). These allow for real-time communication where the client doesn't have to constantly check the server for updated information. Check this out: [Video streaming over websockets using JavaScript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241992/video-streaming-over-websockets-using-javascript). I've done it before, but the code is a bit outdated. You'd also have to either build your own WebSocket server (I used Raspberry Pi) or do the simpler thing and rent a connection.